# WCF web service without SOAPAction header

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap

How can I implement a web service in WCF such that it does not require the SOAPAction header to be present in the request, and would thus dispatch the call using the message body root element name? By default, BasicHttpBinding requires the SOAPAction.

I need this to provide compatibility with a client that does not use SOAPActions.
This is my SOAP message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<messageDeliveryReport xmlns="http://bogus/ns"><status>D</status><systemName>cc</systemName></messageDeliveryReport>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

and I want it to call 'messageDeliveryReport' operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an issue of BasicHttpBinding, it's an issue of adhering to [the SOAP 1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) which says:

```
An HTTP client MUST use this header field when issuing a SOAP HTTP Request.
```

So what you're dealing with is a client that doesn't conform to a standard that's existed since 2000. You might be able to work around this problem by implementing one of the extensibility points of WCF which are explained in greater detail in the MSDN article [Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx), probably either `IDispatchMessageInspector` or `IDispatchOperationSelector`, but the request may not even make it that far since the message really isn't a valid SOAP request to begin with.

Comment: This is because the client was implemented for *.asmx ASP.Net web service and it never used SOAPAction header. But now I think it makes more sense to try to convince client app developers to update the client and make it obey the standard.

Comment: problem is that WCF still needs the SOAPAction header for SOAP 1.2 calls, which is non-compliant with the standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395223%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to build custom behavior for dispatching SOAP messages to operation based on root element of message body.

Comment: `...the client side of these stacks might send messages with an empty or arbitrary HTTP SoapAction header...` I think an empty header is ok, the problem is the header isn't there at all.