# WCF service generated from WSDL not able to use same contract

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have **wsdl** which was **generatede by JAX-WS RI** of a working web service, but i don't have access to the service itself.

Now what i would like to do is, to create my own WCF service out of the wsdl that i got. So i could just switch url's in the config file.

I created service interface with **svcutil.exe**.

```
svcutil my.wsdl my.xsd
```

All seemed ok until i tried to check my service via browser, i got:

**The operations X and Y have the same action ().  Every operation must have a unique action value.**

Hmm.. ok. i checked the interface and realized that, yes, code generator has given each operation same name - "".

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
```

So i replaced all these linse with plain `[OperationContract]` and all seemed to work well until i tried to call my service from client. In config i just modified endpoints address.

The exception i got was: **The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher**

To me it seems like client is requesting operation with no name. How is it possible that working service knows which operation to use?

If i add new my service as a new service reference, all works fine.

What am i missing here?

> **How can i make WCF service to work on same contract it was generated from?**

EDIT:

I did some more debugging. I creted opration

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
public object UnknownAction()
{
    return null;
}
```

When i add breakpoint to this operation i see from `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action` that Action is empty. Message body is totally correct though.

> **Is there some kind of behavior i need to define on the server side?**

current behavior configuration looks like this:

```
    <behavior name="svcBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
```

EDIT vol2

When i create asmx web service and try to call web method from client, i get **SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .**

Comment: What binding you host your new service on?

Comment: not sure, but probably this is what you are looking for? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/06/12/how-to-create-a-wcf-service-for-asmx-client-without-changing-the-client.aspx

Comment: unfortunately no, my problem is that client sends message without SOAPAction header and i don't know how to implement service that should understand these messages.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980801/wcf-web-service-without-soapaction-header) it could be helpful. Also, issue may be at your original service which may not be implemented properly - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466234/empty-soapaction-in-generated-wsdl)